# EXC_BAD_ACCESS(Code=1…. when using NSObject as a delegate

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, delegates, uiactionsheet

I have this code in the .h file :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NFModalPickerView : NSObject

@end

@protocol NFModalPickerViewDelegate<NSObject>
@optional

- (void)titleSelected:(NFModalPickerView *) modalPickerView title:(NSString *) title;

@required

- (void)done:(NFModalPickerView *) modalPickerView;

@end

@interface NFModalPickerView()
{
    id <NFModalPickerViewDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray * objectArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) id <NFModalPickerViewDelegate> delegate;

- (void) show;

@end
```

and this code in the .m file :

```
#import "NFModalPickerView.h"

@interface NFModalPickerView()<UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource>

@end

@implementation NFModalPickerView

@synthesize objectArray;
@synthesize delegate;

UIActionSheet *actionSheet;
UIPickerView *pickerView ;
UISegmentedControl *closeButton;

- (void) show{

    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                             delegate:nil
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];

    CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0);

    pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    pickerView.dataSource = self;
    pickerView.delegate = self;

    [actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];
    pickerView = nil;

    closeButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Done"]];
    closeButton.momentary = YES;
    closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 7.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);
    closeButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    closeButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissActionSheet:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [actionSheet addSubview:closeButton];
    closeButton = nil;

    [actionSheet showInView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];

    [actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return [objectArray count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return [objectArray objectAtIndex:row];
}

-(void) dismissActionSheet:(id)sender {
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet =  (UIActionSheet *)[(UIView *)sender superview];
    [actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    [[self delegate] titleSelected:self title:[objectArray objectAtIndex:row]];
}
@end
```

and finally this code in my ViewController

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    pickerView = [[NFModalPickerView alloc] init];
    pickerView.objectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [pickerView.objectArray addObject:@"Don personnel"];
    [pickerView.objectArray addObject:@"Don d'entreprise"];
    [pickerView setDelegate:self];
    [pickerView show];
    return NO;
}
```

I'm always getting a bad access error when using NFModalPickerView as the delegate of the pickerview. If i put all the code in the view controller using the view controller as the delegate of the picker view it works fine. I need to have a separate class to reuse the modalpickerview and not always put all the code in each of my view controllers. Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: In the view controller, how have you defined 'pickerView'?

Comment: NFModalPickerView *pickerView; Maybe I should try with __strong.

Comment: Where is that definition? Is the exception when interacting with the UIPickerView?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ARC`, UIPickerView 's `delegate` might be auto-released. Either use the `UIViewController` as the `dataSource` and the `delegate` for the `UIPickerView`, or if you are using a separate object to manage the `UIPickerView`, keep it as a property so that it is not released.